# Patience/solitaire-style competitive game for two players

Tags: identify-this-game

I have learnt a (Dutch?) competitive two-player card game similar to Solitaire from my grandparents, who call it 'Stapello'. I am a bit unsure about the spelling because this name returns no results! I am aware that rules and names can get lost in translation a bit over the years, but I was wondering if there's some more information on this game (or a similar one). The game is played with two decks, and the goal is to get rid of all your cards by placing them in the playing area.

[image: Playing area of the game]

1. In preparation of the game the two decks are shuffled and dealt in their entirety to the two players. Both players form a pile of thirteen cards, and put the other (39) cards in their draw piles. The top cards of the two 'thirteen' piles are turned face-up. Then, each player places four cards from their draw pile in the free spaces: place 1-4 for player 1 and place 5-8 for player 2. The first cards (place 1 and 5 respectively) are compared by value (low -> A1-10JQK -> high) to determine who starts; ties are resolved by the next cards (place 2 and 6), etc.
2. At the start of a turn, the player turns around the top card of their draw pile. Then, if possible they carry out any number of the following actions:

   1. They can place a card from their draw, thirteen, or discard piles on one of the 8 ascending stacks in the center. These stacks are formed by placing an ace and stacking consecutive ascending numbers of the same suit (so an 8 of spades could be placed on top of a 7 of spades). These stack have to start with an ace. The relative position of suits in the playing area is not relevant to the game.
   2. They can place a card from their draw, thirteen or discard piles on one of the 8 reverse open stacks/free spaces. Cards need to be consecutive and descending, and the opposite color (red on black, black on red). There are no restrictions on which cards can be placed if the stack/space is empty.
   3. They can place a card from their draw, thirteen or discard piles on the discard pile or thirteen pile of their opponent. The suit needs to match and the number should be adjacent but not equal (6 or 8 on 7). *Players can end up with a large amount of cards on their thirteen pile, and whereas the discard pile ends up getting turned around when their draw pile runs out (see action 5), the cards on the thirteen pile have to be played in the reverse order that they were put down.*
   4. They can move the outermost card of the reverse open stacks to an ascending stack, to a different reverse open stack, or to the discard pile or thirteen pile of their opponent, all following the same rules as in action 1-3 respectively. *This can be used to combine stacks; only one card can be moved at a time but if there is one extra free space two cards could be moved, etc.*
   5. If they have played a card from their draw pile they can turn the next one around. If the pile is empty, the discard pile is turned around (without shuffling) to replace the draw pile. The thirteen pile is never replaced.
   6. If no actions can be performed (or if the player decides to), they can end their turn by placing the topmost card of their draw pile on their discard pile.
3. The other player, at the same time, has to pay attention: if the active player could put any card from their piles or from the playing area on one of the ascending stacks, either directly or by moving cards in the playing area (i.e. action 4), and *instead* plays a card from their piles in another place, the inactive player should say *"Stapello!"*, at which point the active player has to take back their card and put it on their discard pile, at which point their turn ends.
4. If either player plays their last card (in an action that is not Stapello), the game ends and they win.

Is this game known under another name? Is there a more authoritative set of rules?

Comment: What is the question here?  Name verification?  I've played a varient of this which has only 4 "shared" spots (not 8) and both players need to finish.  Not sure what you're asking enough to know if that's an answer or not.

Comment: @joedragons I had tagged it as [tag:identify-this-game] but forgot to add the question in the question body, I have edited it now. This game is competitive, which may have been a bit ambiguous in the rules I wrote down. I am assuming since both players need to finish your variant may not be?

Comment: you're correct in your assumption.  Thanks for the clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the game known as **Russian Bank** or **Crapette**. Other more regional names include **crapot** (Brazil, Portugal), **Zank-Patience**, **Streitpatience**, or **Schikanös–Patience** (Germany), **Stop** or **Touch** (North America), or **Tonj/Tunj/Tonge/Tunge** (طنج, Middle East) according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Bank) and [PAGAT.com](https://www.pagat.com/patience/crapette.html).

The rules listed on Wikipedia are virtually the same, with a minor difference: the 'thirteen' pile (reserve pile), the draw pile (talon), and the discard pile (waste pile) are in various different places in the different examples in the linked sources.